# EntityFrameworkCore logs warnings `Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. QueryCompiler`

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have typical .net5/6 web application, which uses `EFCore 6`, `.net6`, `IMediator`, `PostgreSQL` as DB. This application has simple API controllers that passes execution to IMediator pipeline.
Quite typical application and stack, BUT I see lot of warning messages coming from EFCore:

```
[11:40:07 WRN] Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. Connection
[11:40:07 WRN] Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. QueryExecution
[11:40:07 WRN] Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. QueryCompiler
[11:40:07 WRN] Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. QueryExecution
```

There is nothing about them in Google - it's very strange - Am I first who faced with that?
These errors do not disturb application to function properly, but they're annoying as warnings and makes log nearly unreadable.

What do you think this could be and how I can investigate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It was mistake that errors came from EFCore. I've changed log template and saw that errors are coming from Sentry.

```
16:05:24 [Warning] [Sentry.ISentryClient] Trying to close a span that was already garbage collected. QueryExecution
```

So the reason is that sentry tracing was enabled on this project, and this causes lot of such warnings. Wil write them.